# Categories in new products prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, product, addition

When I add a new product I need to disable "Using the category list". Only I need "Using the search bar" anc "Associated categories".

Any idea that which template, controller I need to modify?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @Mireia, Welcome to stackOverflow. Could you please add more details ?

Comment: I have more categories and when I trye add new product the process is very slow, and I want disable the upload of categories and subcategories tree, but I don't find where I have to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is so easy to achieve what you want. First of all, we are talking about a piece of Prestashop that is still relying a lot on their first version code (not totally covered by Symfony yet). I don't think there are hooks where you could hold to try to modify that behavior.

This lands to a single possible solution: editing Prestashop core. I have no idea what your skills are but obviously, this would be quite hard to achieve and probably not even recommended (a possible upgrade would reset these potential changes). Sorry for not giving you good news.

Best regards